# Better layout express, pass app and io object to routes

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

I was working in express and trying to implement a better structure for the project, how would it be possible to reconstruct the layout and put all of the routes in a seperate folder. At the moment my folder structure looks like

```
import express from 'express';
const app = express()
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World')
})
app.listen(5656, () => {
    console.log('http://localhost:5656')
})
```

Just a dummy example but lets say i wanted to seperate the routes and everything in a seperate folder, how would i approach it? Additionally i have socket object which i would also want to pass. If somebody can point me in a right direction of a better layout, your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to create something like this

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()


require('./routes')(app)

app.listen(config.port,()=>{
    console.log('we are now running')
})
```

Note that when you require routes you send an object of `(app)` itself, so in a route file you need to recieve this app by following this logic.

```
const GetController = require('./controllers/GetController')

module.exports = (app) => {
    //can do other methods in the same way
    app.get('/get',
        GetController.getController
    )
}
```

and inside of your GetController you can define functions such as

```
module.exports = {

    getController(req, res) {
        res.send({
            message: 'Get Controller'
        })
    }

}
```

Hope that helps, if needs to pass socket.io object then just add it to your `require('/routes')(app,io)` and in a route file `module.exports = (app, io) =>{}`

Hope it helps